# Does The Witness change on your second playthrough?

Tags: the-witness

Is the game different on your second playthrough?  I just started my second game after my first one ended, and almost immediately encountered several new things.  Did I just not notice them before, or is the game changed?

Comment: After all the work you did during your first playthrough, you will notice a LOT of different things right at the beginning if you start again. The game trains/conditions you to be attentive to a number of different elements that would have been simply invisible the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly confident there isn't any, after spending another hour trying to figure it out, only to be disappointed to notice nothing different.

Also, according to [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheWitness/comments/67c9p5/comment/dgplinj), there should be many others finding nothing different as well.